# Login with Flask Backend and React Frontend

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, authentication, flask

I am currently working on a project whose backend I will be writing using Flask (cannot change that), and the frontend will be developed using React by someone else (cannot change that too). I am currently working on the login functionality and I have a few questions. I am really just beginning backend development, so please excuse me if I have some redundant questions or beginner-level questions.
I am curious as to how the login-system as a whole will be handled, not just in terms of actual login - but more so when it comes to restricting access from non-logged in users.

The tutorials and online courses I have taken on Flask have done one of 2 approaches.
The first approach was using Flask-Login to login a user and ensure that they are logged in as they navigate to different websites. This was pretty straightforward to understand and relatively easy to implement. However, (and please correct me if I'm wrong), this would require all the navigation and redirecting to be handled server-side. Therefore, we would not be utilizing React's ability to create single-page websites (instead relying on hyperlinks from each page to the next), which is far from ideal and something that we'd like to avoid if possible.
The second approach was using JWT tokens. Again correct me if I'm wrong, but we would only be able to check that the JWT token is correct if it is included in an HTTP request, which again makes creating single-page websites not feasible. Another issue with JWT is that the tokens expire fairly quickly (around 15 minutes as far as my research tells me), which is not suitable for our project because it would require users to be logged in for a longer duration. I have read about refreshing JWT tokens, but I would like to know more about the feasibility of such a process given the short expiration time (we would have to do a lot of refreshes).

My main question is:
How can we create single-page websites while preventing non-logged in users from accessing restricted pages?
But also please feel free to give me any feedback or concerns about what I have talked about.

Thank you in advance and sorry for the long post

Comment: just use JWT...

Comment: You can decide the life length of the token yourself, and you just add the token to the header when you want some data from the backend.

Comment: @mama can you please elaborate on how I can "decide the life length of the token"? the research I have done (before posting the question and after reading your answer) and it seems to be that this is not possible. thank you.

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/ look for `JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA`

Comment: @mama Thank you very much! If you'd like to leave an answer instead of a comment, I would accept it on SO.

Comment: What you need is simply to include *something* in every HTTP request made to the backend that allows you to identify the user. You _could_ do that by including the username and password in every single request, though that's not usually a good idea, as it gives a lot of air time for those credentials in plain text. Alternatives include session cookies, JWT tokens, any other sort of token, or whatever scheme you can cook up yourself (though you should probably use proven existing schemes which are known to be secure). This is all fundamentally frontend and backend agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use JWT, you can add the token to the header of the HTTP request and you can set the lifetime (`JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA`) of the token - check this link https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT